# Best way to use DTO on WCF Client side

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, dto

I would like some advice about what's the correct way to implement the following situation.

I have three solutions a WCF service which uses Entity Framework to communicate with a SQL database, a WPF Sever which hosts the service, and a WPF Client which consumes the service. I'm thinking about what is the correct way to implement DTO.

Currently for each EF entity, I have a DTO which is used to communicate with the client. So the client request something from the service, the service gets the information from the database and does some logic with it, then the return objects are mapped to DTO (using AutoMapper) and sent to the client.

At the client side, I have to add some extensions to these DTO, for instance I need to add a few autocalculated properties, and methods.

I ended up with two ideas

First idea is create a partial class for every DTO I need to add logic.

Advantage I see this way: I don't have to rewrite the entire DTO, only add the extra properties and methods I need, and I have to map only once EFEntity => ServiceDTO and ServiceDTO => EFEntity

Disadvantage: I would like to set to private some properties, make others readonly. But no matter the access level or setters I write on the Service DTO it always get generated as `public .... { get; set; }` on the client.

Here's an example of this approach

```
//AT THE WCF SERVICE: DTO
[DataContract]
public class BajaRoturaDTO
{
    [DataMember] public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public int NoVale { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public UsuarioDTO Usuario { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Comentario { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public DepartamentoDTO Departamento { get; set; }
    [DataMember] private List<Instance> _instances { get; set; } //I would like to make this private but it's autogenerated public on the Client

    [DataContract]
    public class Instance
    {
        [DataMember] public int ValidationState { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public ProductoInstanceDTO TargetInstance { get; set; }
    }
}

//AT THE WPF CLIENT: DTO PARTIAL CLASS
public partial class BajaRoturaDTO
{
    public BajaRoturaDTO()
    {
        _instances = new List<Instance>();
    }

    public BajaRoturaDTO(DateTime defaultDate)
    {
        Fecha = defaultDate;
        _instances = new List<Instance>();

    }
    [Magic] public List<Instance> Instances { get => new List<Instance>(_instances); }

    [Magic] public decimal ImporteCosto { get => _instances.Sum(x => x.ImporteVenta); }

    [Magic] public decimal ImporteVenta { get => _instances.Sum(x => x.ImporteCosto); }

    [Magic] public string TotalProductos { get => _instances.Count() + " producto(s)"; }

    public partial class Instance
    {
        [Magic] public decimal ImporteCosto { get => Cantidad * TargetInstance.Producto.PrecioCosto; }

        [Magic] public decimal ImporteVenta { get => Cantidad * TargetInstance.Producto.PrecioVenta; }

        public async Task Validate(DateTime targetDate)
        {
            ValidationState = await TargetInstance.Validate(targetDate, Cantidad);
        }
    }

    //METHODS
    public async Task AddInstance(Instance target)
    {
        var matchInList = _instances.FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.TargetInstance.Producto.Id == target.TargetInstance.Producto.Id
            && x.TargetInstance.Departamento.Id == target.TargetInstance.Departamento.Id);

        if (matchInList is null)
        {
            _instances.Add(target);
            await target.Validate(Fecha);
        }
        else
        {
            matchInList.Cantidad += target.Cantidad;
            await matchInList.Validate(Fecha);
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged("Instances");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ImporteCosto");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ImporteVenta");
        RaisePropertyChanged("TotalProductos");
    }
//More methods
```

PD: the `[Magic]` decorator is an extension I installed to automate `INotifyPropertyChange`.

The other idea is create a complete new class for every DTO on the WPF client and use AutoMapper again to map from ServiceDTO to ClientClass

Advantage I see: I can define autocalculated properties, private field, methods and everything I want

Disadvantage I see: I have to recreate every DTO again and perform more mapping (EFEntity => ServiceDTO => CientClass and ClientClass => ServiceDTO => EFEntity)

I need your opinion on what do you think about this two approach or if there's a better way.

Thank you for your time and excuse my English if I have some spelling errors

Comment: A dto is just for transferring data. You should keep it clean and copy properties from that to a viewmodel (vm). And back to a dto for update. Put your calculated properties etc just in the vm.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm creating another class to map from DTO and use it in the VM